# Goggle Analytics 4 Current Active User Information

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am trying to use real-time data in the data api to find expanded information on current active users. Is it possible to call the user dimension for range of 1 min to see data such as acquisition link, ip, user agent? I tried creating new audience but I don’t think that updates fast enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom dimensions and calculated metrics and dimensions aren't available in RT reports. RT reports are there kinda more for show than to really be useful.

Even if you pay for GA360, it's still useless as a RT Analytics tool.

There are generally two approaches to get RT analytics. The cheap and the expensive ways.

The cheap way is to add a parallel tracking from your GTM to also send key events into an endpoint, which can be a cloud endpoint, something like the Google App Engine. Then from there, using say BQ API, you reroute the events directly into BQ. A bit of ETL and boom! You have your fresh data in BQ with only seconds of delay.

The expensive and the "proper" way to do it is via implementing CDP solutions or by using more enterprise analytics solutions.